# Error search mean and variance of image with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, types, mean

Try to find mean and variance of image. 
Output is: 
M = -5.8099e-16 
D = -4.97692e-23

```
Mat _mat = imread("img.jpg",0);
_mat.convertTo(mat, CV_32F, 1.0/255, 0);    
Mat mean, dev;
mean.convertTo(mean, CV_32F);
dev.convertTo(dev, CV_32F);
meanStdDev(_mat, mean, dev);
float M = mean.at<float>(0,0);
float D = dev.at<float>(0,0);
cout << M << D
```

What's wrong?

Comment: we don't see your output, so it's hard to tell what went wrong, but try to feed in a cv::Scalar for mean and dev instead of a cv::Mat (which also has double, not float type)

Comment: yes, thanks. It's works:
Scalar mean,dev;
    meanStdDev(_mat, mean, dev);
    float M = mean.val[0];
    float D = dev.val[0];

Comment: so, it was basically a double vs float issue. please dare to answer your own question, once you acquired enough karma.

Comment: Isn't this just getting the value of the first element in each matrix? Is this meaningful in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scalar mean,dev; 
meanStdDev(_mat, mean, dev); 
double M = mean.val[0]; 
double D = dev.val[0];
```

Comment: I get an error that the first two parameters of `meanStdDev` must be `MaOfDouble` and I'm not sure what their equivalent of `.val` is. I'm also confused by why if `.val[0]` just access the value of the first element, what use it is. Doesn't it just relate to one corner pixel of the image?